# How to unmask websockets when using tcpdump or tshark?

Tags: bash, websocket, wireshark, tcpdump, tshark

Without having to launch Wireshark or store and analyze packets later.

How to have a live view of this without that gibberish that websockets do?

```
tcpdump -nnXSs 0 port 1234
```

Answer (score 4):

```
tshark -r out.pcap -Y websocket.payload -E occurrence=l -T fields -e text
```

The unmasked text is handed off to the "Line-Based text data" dissector, so you need to use the field selector for that, and also set the occurrence to the last instance of that field in the packet to remove "noise". I've also added a filter to limit the output to packets that contain a websocket payload.

by grahamb in https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/60725/how-to-dump-websockets-live-with-tshark

Answer (score 1):

The feature was removed in the version 2.0 of the Wireshark.

So have to get the following packages from Ubuntu trusty 14.04 and install them:

`sudo dpkg -i wireshark-common_1.10.6-1_amd64.deb tshark_1.10.6-1_amd64.deb libwireshark3_1.10.6-1_amd64.deb libwsutil3_1.10.6-1_amd64.deb libwiretap3_1.10.6-1_amd64.deb libgnutls26_2.12.23-12ubuntu2.7_amd64.deb libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.4_amd64.deb`

Disable updates:

```
sudo apt-mark hold tshark
```

Fix dependencies:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

Command to dump content:

```
tshark -e websocket.payload.text_unmask -Tfields port 1234
```